# Deleting an object in C++ deletes objects inside the deleted object?

Tags: c++, object

I have a game class, cube class and a solution class. In my main function, I am creating a game object g and the game object has an array of cube type objects and a stack of solution type objects. In the main function, before exiting, I am deleting the object g by calling delete[] g;

I wanted to know if this will delete all the objects in the array and the stack as well? Or will I still have a memory leak?

Sample code:

```
int main(void)
{

Game* g = new Game();
//Do something like addCube by calling functions in game

delete g;
}
```

Game Constructor:

```
public: Game()    
    {    
        int nx;    
        cout<<"Enter the number of cubes in the game ";    
        cin>>nx;    
        this->numOfCubes=nx;    
        cubes = new Cube[nx];        
        this->ref=0;    
    }
```

Sample of game functions

```
    void Game::addCube()
{    
    if(ref<numOfCubes)
    {   
        cubes[ref].getSides();      
        ref++;   
        cubes[ref]->Sno = ref;    

    }
    else
        cout<<"All the cubes are already in the game"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide some example code so we know what you're really talking about. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @FredLarson : Code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever other problems you may have, your `addCube()` function is flawed. Comments added:

```
{
    Cube* c = new Cube(); // allocate a Cube object
    c->getSides();
    cubes[ref]=*c; // dereference pointer and store a copy of the object
    ref++;
    c->Sno = ref; // modify allocated Cube (not the same object as cubes[ref])
}
// pointer c goes out of scope and you leak the allocated memory
```

There's no reason to use `new` in this code.

Comment: @user3000837: It looks more correct but I think you want `cubes[ref].Sno = ref`. Since the array contains objects and not pointers you should just use `.` instead of the `->` operator.

Comment: Yes,I did that and I am using delete[] g->cubes; delete g; before exiting the game to avoind any kind of memory leak. Am going in the right direction now?

Comment: @user3000837: Just remember that every `new` or `new[]` must have a matching `delete` or `delete[]` somewhere in your code. My advice is to avoid manual memory management unless you have no other choice. When you do need a dynamic container start with `std::vector` or another standard C++ container. It will allow you to focus on your code instead of fiddly resource management.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about an array of actual objects, then  yes, they will be destroyed properly. If you have an array of pointer, you'll have to delete each object (assuming each object was created with `new`).

EDIT:

Well, you have trouble right here:

```
int main(void)
{

Game* g = new Game();
//Do something like addCube by calling functions in game

delete[] g;
}
```

`g` is not pointing to an array, just a single instance. So `delete [] g;` is undefined behavior. It should be just `delete g;` Better yet, don't use dynamic allocation at all:

```
int main(void)
{

Game g;
//Do something like addCube by calling functions in game

// No delete necessary since you're using automatic allocation.
}
```

As for your `cubes` array, you'll have  to delete the array itself, since it is created with `new []`. Be sure to use `delete [] cubes;`. But you are leaking cubes in `addCube()`, as pointed out by Blastfurnace. I think you're trying to do a dynamic array, in which case `std::vector` would be your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

No the inner objects will persist, but if you know you want to delete inner objects every time you can create a destructor method of the style `~ClassName()` inside the the class definition, inside this destructor method, you can call destructor methods for each of the inner objects you wish to delete. Just remember that if these objects exist elsewhere in your code, you will get unexpected behavior or more likely a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `delete` on an object will only recurse to delete the objects within it if that object's destructor manually does the `delete` on each of them. There is no automatic deletion or garbage collection in c++.